# TempData gets overrided when I try to ReturnRedirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, tempdata

I want to redirect to a previous page after I submit some data in database. I am using a `TempData` to retrieve `ID` on current Page, then I am going on the page with the form I want to submit (`which have an ID`), but after the `POST` method is fired `TempData` gets overrided by `current page ID` which is the page with the form and I want to `ReturnRedirect` to initial page with its ID.

Here the code:

Controller with GET method where I retrieve the ID:

```
var currentID = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];          
TempData["currentId"] = currentID;
```

Controller with POST method where I try to redirect:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Editing records in database
    ....
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Jobs", 
        new { controller = "JobsController", action = "Details", id = TempData["currentId"] });
}
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something failed");
return View();
```

I am using this approach because its working if the current action with a POST method doesn't have an ID.

Thank you for any suggestions.

EDIT:

I have a Details of Jobs:

```
    // GET: Jobs/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(Guid id)
    {
        var currentID = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];          
        TempData["currentId"] = currentID;

        var currentUserTemp = LoggedUserId;
        TempData["userID"] = currentUserTemp;

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Job job = db.Jobs.Find(id);
        if (job == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(job);
    }
```

But from this page I want a link to a page where I edit current user data.

View Details page Code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Company Details", "Edit", "UserAdmin", new { id = TempData["userID"] }, null)
```

Now I am on edit User Page, I edit the form and use save button (which triggers POST method) I want to use the other TempData variable to `ReturnRedirect` on Details Page but since both pages have ID`s, TempData gets overrided with last ID from the URL which is the ID of the user not ID.

Comment: where have you written `var currentID = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];          
TempData["currentId"] = currentID;` code

Comment: can you make you question a little more clear. Add some code if needed

Comment: @MyName - please add your action method(get and post both) signature. If you can use same name for get and post action method then no need to redirect simply return View().

Comment: I tried but didn't work I just ended up using Sessions for this case instead TempData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that TempData exists only during the time of a HTTP Request. Maybe it's a clue to your problem (I can't find all the interactions between Controllers and Views in your code so I can't be sure).

Comment: Well your answer was a very good hint, and I started looking for Sessions, and it did it. I was figuring out pretty much that my TempData gets flushed away but I tried to make it persist. Thanks